# Deciding how and what to test in a simple android project

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm playing around with unit testing, and I am build simple android app that has a login screen (for learning purposes).

I use the [MVP](http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/) (model view presenter) pattern, and these are the classes I have:

- LoginFragment (hosted in MainActivity), implements ILoginView
- LoginPresenter, gets an ILoginView reference (in our case, a reference LoginFragment)
- LoginService (injected into the LoginPresenter)
- Validator (injected into the LoginService)

I have the following test classes in mind, and I'd like to get some feedback:

- create a ValidatorTest that tests each validation
- create a LoginService that mocks the validators response and tests the login according to that response
- create a LoginPresenterTest that mocks Validator, LoginService and ILoginView's behavior, and tests the different calls to its

Does this structure make sense? Any input?

Comment: Unit Test your POJOs. Use `Robolectric` and `Junit`. UI/Integration tests for actual "stories" such as the "user logs into the Application". Make that story a test: "UserLoginTest". Use `Espresso` to test the user logging in.

Comment: Thanks! should the UserLoginTest be an Android instrumentation test? and what about the tests I wrote? does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, that is what I said in the previous comment. You can test however you like, I am just explaining a simple "model" you can go by in order to start testing.